# Ionic 5 custom Icon / Splash IOS 6.2.0

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am a bit confused. I build my app with Ionic Cordova. I update the ios platform from 5.1.0 to 6.2.0.
After i update my Platform, the custom app icons was gone. My own app icons are gone and the default icon back.
I try this:

```
ionic cordova resources
```

but nothing happens...

In my xCode project the icons are displayed, but the completed app shows the default ionic icons. So i have no idea why my custom icons doesn't displayed. The command ionic cordova resources works, but something else doesn't work and i have no idea what is the problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing and adding the platform again.